# Interface methods are not visible on my implementing class

Tags: c#, .net

I have a generic interface, and a class which implements it.  When I call the interface method in a third class, I get an error that implies the method isn't visible/doesn't exist:

```
public interface MyInterface<T>
{
    List<T> Convert<L>(List<L> inputs);
}

public class MyClass : MyInterface<string>
{
    List<string> Convert<L>(List<L> inputs) { ... }
}

public class Program
{
    static public void Main(String[] args)
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.Convert((new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3}).ToList());
    }
}
```

This results in the error:

Error   CS1061  'MyClass' does not contain a definition for 'Comvert' and no accessible extension method 'Convert' accepting a first argument of type 'MyClass' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: In the implementation, make the method public: `public List<string> Convert<L>...`. Also, the method expects a `List<string>` but you pass an `Integer[]`

Comment: Works fine for me - please [check out yourself](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYAYAEMEBYDcqG2CAdADJgB2AjoSqgLICeAwhAIYDOXmAtm049MAXkxUApgHdMLdty4AKAJT0B8nqVYB7KgDcJAJ2CLFkmQG0AupgDemBABpMcZwGYAvstIAVbZS4TZVVUIjdMamAjADMOAGMJWWYASSoow1iEgB4fAD5UW1RMYswA4BzczB19I3KfclzFMpyGiKoABwBXYC4QlA9QtHD4JI1eECTU9MyJLJx0fJRClBLscOb5yuqDYxbG5vrK6i6e5TtsAHZxTogIfEwB/qA)

Answer (score -1):

You're assuming another method signature, as you are trying to pass an array to a method, that actually accepts a `List<T>` instead. You can't pass an array as an argument, if a `List<T>` is required.

Also, make the method you're implementing public, so that you really implement the method from the interface, instead of creating one that is independent and private.

Comment: I've updated my example (the error was in the example, not the actual code).  As for it being public, I get an error saying I can't make it public.  Also aren't interface methods public anyway?

Comment: To add to this, in my code, the interface is explicitly implemented, as in my actual code I have constraints about the generic types

Comment: Why don't you just show us your actual code? You don't have to include the entire content of the method if it is not relevant. We can't help you if you show us something that doesn't match your actual code.

Comment: Also, why don't you just create a new `List<T>` instance directly, instead of "casting" an array afterwards with `ToList()`? You could just do: `new List<int> {1, 2, 3}` instead of `(new int[] {1, 2, 3}).ToList()`.